# Approaches for creating REST Web services?

Tags: web-services, rest

i am new to REST Service development. I compared the development mechanism for both REST and WS web services and i found that you can create a WS web service using WSDL file that is the top down appraoch (Correct me if i am wrong) and using bottom up approach also, that is generating the classes manually. 
But when it comes to REST web service development you have to follow bottom up approach only that is generating the classes manually. NetBeans IDE provides certain wizards for creating REST web service quickly from databases, entity classes and patterns. 
I had also seen when you are developing web service in eclipse and you are using wizard in eclipse IDE, you can create a REST web service from WSDL file. I found this very strange. My question here is what are the approaches we can have for creating REST web services. Can we create REST web services using top-down and bottom up approached. If yes then please provide me details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to describe a REST service using a contract. This is the intent of WADL and WSDL 2.0. WADL is specifically a REST contract, whereas WSDL 2.0 evolved from the original WSDL spec. to support all HTTP bindings. Since REST services rely on the use of HTTP methods and headers to exchange messages a WSDL 2.0 contract can work. There is a really good explanation here: http://ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-2-wsdl-and-wadl

For development of REST services, I'm not sure if NetBeans, Eclipse or other tools specifically support automated REST service from WSDL generation. I would imagine that most are still intended for SOAP service creation. At this point I think WSDL 2.0 and WADL can be used to describe a REST service, but are not intended for automated generation of a REST service.

REST services are simple HTTP request/response,and therefore don't require complex stubs. In most cases it would probably take more time to write the WSDL describing the REST service, than it would take to write the REST service itself.